# exiftool write xmp tag

Tags: exiftool, xmp

I am trying to write a new value for a XMP tag using exiftool but for some reason the tag is not being recognized.

Reading the field works:

```
exiftool -PropertyId /Users/user/test.jpg
Property Id                     : 17934
```

But when trying to write a value for PropertyId tag, does not work.I did try also to use -xmp:PropertyId but I get the same result:

```
exiftool -PropertyId=12345 /Users/user/test.jpg
Warning: Tag 'PropertyId' is not defined
Nothing to do.
```

Exporting the metadata shows that the field is there: (I only copied the xmp section)

```
exiftool -xmp -b -a /Users/user/test.jpg > data.xmp
...
 <rdf:Description rdf:about=''
  xmlns:xmp='http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/'>
  <xmp:Brand>Brand Name</xmp:Brand>
  <xmp:CreateDate>2015-07-08T11:45:21</xmp:CreateDate>
  <xmp:CreatorTool>CreatorTool</xmp:CreatorTool>
  <xmp:FacilityName>The Restaurant Name</xmp:FacilityName>
  <xmp:MetadataDate>2015-09-14T13:12:51-06:00</xmp:MetadataDate>
  <xmp:ModifyDate>2015-09-14T13:12:51-06:00</xmp:ModifyDate>
  <xmp:PropertyId>00000</xmp:PropertyId>
  <xmp:PropertyName>Property Name</xmp:PropertyName>
  <xmp:ShootDate>2016-03-12</xmp:ShootDate>
 </rdf:Description>...
```

I am missing something? Test file is here: [test.jpg](http://www.filedropper.com/test_25552)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exiftool cannot edit metadata it does not have a definition for, as it is in this case.  In fact, your example XMP shows a lot of tags which it says are part of the "xap" group but are not actually part of that (very old) standard, including `Brand`, `FacilityName`, `PropertyName`, and `ShootDate`.  You'll find that none of those are directly editable by exiftool.  Probably not by any other program except the one that originally wrote it.

If you want exiftool to be able to write those tags, you'll need to create definitions for those tags. See the [ExifTool Example Config file](https://exiftool.org/config.html) for details.

Also take note, as I said, "xap" is a very old standard and has long since been replaced.  Exiftool will update the tags it does know to the newer standards.  For details see the [XMP xmp tags entry](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/XMP.html#xmp).